# Using "have" as a causative verb: have someone fooled

Tags: verbs

I know that in the following sentences, the actions are most likely not done by the subjects but by someone else:

> I had my hair cut last week.
>
> Paul had his car fixed yesterday.

But I'm not sure about this one:

> He had all of us fooled.

Does it mean it's someone else that fooled us by his request/order? Is there any difference if I put it this way:

> He fooled all of us.

Are there any rules by which we can judge how exactly this kind of usage really means?

Comment: In theory it _could_ mean that he employed someone else to fool us, but most people would understand it to mean 'he fooled us all'. It's a different sense of _had_, meaning something like 'He put us all in the situation of being fooled'.